# Como transformar linhas em colunas em uma base de dados grande?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, big-data

Boa noite.

Eu tenho uma tabela de 545 mil linhas e 2 colunas. Na coluna 1 eu tenho 2585 dados únicos, e na coluna 2, 25 mil dados únicos. Um pedaço dessa tabela é o seguinte fragmento:

| Disease | Factor |
| --- | --- |
| Parkinson Disease, Secondary | Dengue |
| Parkinson Disease, Secondary | MPTP Poisoning |
| Ischemic Attack, Transient | Dopamine |
| Ischemic Attack, Transient | Arrhythmias, Cardiac |
| Pregnancy Complications | Diabetic Ketoacidosis |
| Pregnancy Complications | Arrhythmias, Cardiac |

Eu preciso transformar essa tabela em uma matriz binária, transformando as colunas "factor" em linhas. Dessa maneira:

|  | Dengue | MPTP Poisoning | Dopamine | Arrhythmias, Cardiac | Diabetic Ketoacidosis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parkinson Disease, Secondary | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ischemic Attack, Transient | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Pregnancy Complications | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Eu estava usando R (código abaixo), mas está demorando demais. Deixei 5 horas rodando e ele fez13 linhas da matriz. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Pode ser em Python tbm.

```
for (i in 2:2585) {
  linhas=grep(matrix[i,1],dados[,1])
  n=length(linhas)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    coluna=grep(dados[linhas[j],2],matrix[1,])
    matrix[linhas[j],coluna]=1
  }
}

------- dados é a tabela e matrix, seria a tabela transformada. Eu inicialmente zerei todas as entradas de matrix.
```

Comment: Você conhece SQL ou tem acesso a algum DBMS? Essa tabela está em que formato?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Em R, pode converter de formato longo para comprido, usando `lenght` como função agregadora. `tidyr::pivot_wider`, `reshape2::dcast` e `data.table::dcast` podem ser usados; para dados grandes, recomendo o último:

```
library(data.table)

dados <- fread(text = c("Disease;Factor
                         Parkinson Disease, Secondary;Dengue
                         Parkinson Disease, Secondary;MPTP Poisoning
                         Ischemic Attack, Transient;Dopamine
                         Ischemic Attack, Transient;Arrhythmias, Cardiac
                         Pregnancy Complications;Diabetic Ketoacidosis
                         Pregnancy Complications;Arrhythmias, Cardiac"))

dados.w <- dcast(dados, Disease ~ Factor, length)

dados.w
#>                         Disease Arrhythmias, Cardiac Dengue Diabetic Ketoacidosis Dopamine MPTP Poisoning
#> 1:   Ischemic Attack, Transient                    1      0                     0        1              0
#> 2: Parkinson Disease, Secondary                    0      1                     0        0              1
#> 3:      Pregnancy Complications                    1      0                     1        0              0
```

Se seus dados estão em arquivo de texto plano, carregar com `fread` é a maneira mais eficiente. Se Já tiver os dados carregados como data.frame, pode setá-los como data.table com `setDT(dados)`, ou indique `as.data.table` ao rodar o `dcast`:

```
dcast(as.data.table(dados), Disease ~ Factor, length)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Carlos Eduardo. Deu certo!

Comment: [Não precisa agradecer, apenas use o sistema de votação de site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)